# how to getting number of records after union operation..?

Tags: sql, database, union

I have a query like this:

```
select author1 
from books_group 
where category='cse' 
union 
select author2 
from books_group 
where category='cse' 
union 
select author3 
from books_group 
where category='cse'
```

the above query union the all the records that are comes from three select commands..

my task is to count the number of records we have after the execution of above sql command...

and i trying the below query but it gives an error..

" select count(*) from (select author1 from books_group where category='cse' union select author2 from books_group where category='cse' union select author3 from books_group where category='cse') "

then, how to get the number of recors after the union operation..???

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you plan to do with the data after you retrieve it? [Both queries] Presumably you have some-type of program utilizing this data.  Is the purpose of the last query to simply display how many results were found to the user? [Programming Language, etc is help]

Comment: What is the error? and which database are you running this against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, you need to specify an alias for your subselect:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    (
    select author1 from books_group where category='cse' union
    select author2 from books_group where category='cse' union
    select author3 from books_group where category='cse'
    ) a
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    select count(*) from 
(select author1 from books_group where category='cse' 
union 
select author2 from books_group where category='cse' 
union 
select author3 from books_group where category='cse')A
```